# Get Item Position From Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-preferences, android-listfragment, android-support-library

Since `PreferenceFragment` is not available in the support library I created a `ListFragment` to show a list of settings to a user since I don't have a lot of settings to show. I also created a custom `ArrayAdapter` to customize the list items. I need to handle when a user checks one of the `CheckBox`s so I can save weather or not it was checked. So if its checked then it will stay checked until the user uncheckes it. This would be much easier if there was only one setting in the list but there are 2 for now and I might need to add more. So I need to be able to determine which one was checked. I can handle the check and uncheck fine I just cant find a way to determine which one was checked.

**THE CODE**

Here is my list item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView android:id="@+id/pref_edit_text" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:layout_weight="5"/>
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/pref_check_box" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1" android:onClick="onCheckBoxClick"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/pref_edit_text2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Here is `getView()` in my adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //mIntCheckBoxPosition = position;
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mMainActivity.getAssets(), "fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");
        LayoutInflater inflater = mMainActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(mIntLayoutId, parent, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_edit_text);
        text.setText(mStringArrayTitle[position]);
        text.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);

        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_edit_text2);
        text.setText(mStringArraySubTitle[position]);
        text.setTypeface(tf);

        mMainActivity.setTitle("Settings");

        return view;
    }
```

And here is where I handle when a `CheckBox` is clicked which is in the `ListFragment`:

```
    public void onCheckBoxClick(View view) {
        boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        Editor editor = mMainActivity.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY_CHECK_BOX, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.check_box :
                if (isChecked) {
                    editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_ROUNDING, true).commit();
                }
                else {
                    editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_ROUNDING, false).commit();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what my settings look like:
[image]

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
1. I have tried setting a variable in the adapter to the item position and using a getter to get the position, but that only returns the position of the last item shown.
2. I have tried using some of the methods in `ListFragment` to get the position of the `CheckBox` but they always return -1.
3. I have done a lot of Googling and searching on SO but I have not been able to find a solution to get this to work.

So if anyone knows of a way I can get the position of the `CheckBox` or any other ways I might be able to tell which one was clicked I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use Action SherlockBar? it would save you a lot of headache since it has pretty much a template for a settings fragment. Plus a native 4.0 look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `setTag` to add an `int` to the view indicating its position, and then retreive that later using `getTag`. Ex:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ... // your other code here

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_check_box);
    checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));

}
```

Then, in your `onCheckBoxClick`:

```
public void onCheckBoxClick(View view) {
    Integer pos;
    pos = (Integer) view.getTag();

    ... // do what you want with `pos` here

}
```